# Creating a tag manager trigger to not fire 3rd party tags when users disable 3rd party tracking

Tags: javascript, html, tags, google-tag-manager

On my client's websites, we have a large amount of third party tags due to using different media publishers. When users disable third party cookies, the tags still load on the page.

Is there a way to create a `javascript` to only fire third party tags within our tag management solution to only fire for users that allow for third party tracking?

Comment: How do users disable third-party tracking?

Comment: Sure - set a cookie when they disable tracking, read that into a variable type "First party cookie", build a trigger type "pageview", condition "cookie is undefined" and use it as a trigger exception - is that the kind of thing you are looking for ? Or are you looking for a mechanism by which you can detect if tracking is disabled (I don't think we have enough info to help there).